# How can I create a nested object from a list of keys and a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to come up with a script that would take an array of keys and one value and return an object:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
value = 'hello';
```

And I am trying to get this:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'hello'}}}
```

My code:

```
var data = {};
for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var key = keys[i];
  if (i < keys.length -1) {
     if (data[key] === undefined) {
       data[key] = {};
    }
  } else {
    data[key] = value;
  }
  data = data[key];
}
```

Also I want to make sure that any data that would already be contained in the `data` value would not get erase whenever it uses a different key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight), like this

```
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var value = 'hello';

console.log(keys.reduceRight(function (pastResult, currentKey) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[currentKey] = pastResult;
    return obj;
}, value));
// { a: { b: { c: 'hello' } } }
```

`reduceRight` will process the array from the right to left. And everytime we create a new object and store the old object against the current key name. So, as we iterate one by one, we are increasing the nesting of objects. We pass `value` as the last parameter, which will be used as the `pastResult` the very first time.

---

If you want to fix your original code, you just have to stop assigning new objects to `data` and use another variable, like this

```
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    value = 'hello',
    data = {},
    temp = data;

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    if (i < keys.length - 1) {
        if (temp[key] === undefined) {
            temp[key] = {};
        }
    } else {
        temp[key] = value;
    }
    temp = temp[key];
}

console.log(data)
// { a: { b: { c: 'hello' } } }
```

Even this can be written succinctly, like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
    temp = (temp[keys[i]] = {});
}
temp[keys[keys.length - 1]] = value;
```

We iterate all the `keys` except the last one and assign a new object to the current key every time and since we assign it back to `temp`, on the next iteration `temp` will refer the newly created object. And finally, we assign the `value` to the last element of `keys`.